How to perform phonon convergence?
I am conducting phonon calculations for the CsPbI3₃ perovskite structure. How can a convergence test be performed for phonons? Which parameter should be checked in the output file to ensure convergence? Do we need to verify the convergence of frequencies at specific q-points?

+1 but please make a better title!

The usual advice for convergence testing with phonons is to look at stress convergence with basis size (etc).
This is because you can think of an applied stress as being a population of the long-wavelength limit q=0 phonon modes, and accordingly how well the stress is described is a good proxy quantity for phonon convergence. Naturally the gold standard would be to converge the phonons themselves explicitly, but this is considerably more computationally expensive.
Hope that helps,
Rob

Thank you for your answer. But i am confused that exactly which parameter i need to see in the output file of phonons to check the convergence? I am new to the field and unable to find the proper answers on phonon convergence and it is also computationally intensive so I don't want to waste resources.
